# Printing Envelopes in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice.org, printing, epson

I have an Epson RX580 multi-function printer, and OpenOffice refuses to print envelopes on it correctly.  I've tried changing every setting I could, but it keeps on cutting off the return address.  Has anyone found a solution?  I had researched the matter in vain ... I'd hate to have to boot into Windows just to print an envelope!

Comment: What do you mean by "cut off"?  Is it trying to print too close to the border?

Comment: It prints the envelopes as if they were full sheets of paper, so it doesn't print everything on the envelope.

Comment: Why does it have to be OpenOffice or Windows? There are other Ubuntu packages available...

Comment: What would you recommend?  I'd like a DEDICATED envelope program if one is available....

Answer (score 2):

My other suggestion is to try glabels see here for some ideas: http://blog.worldlabel.com/2010/advanced-usage-with-glabels-labelscards-linuxgnu.html, glabels is a program designed mainly for labels, business cards and so on but custom layouts can be made with it so I think you could make a template for envelopes, its description says it supports mail merge from sources such as CSV files, vCards and Evolution data servers.

Comment: I wonder why you were marked down, glabels is a good suggestion.

Comment: I had suggested along with what I have there now that common sense dictates that he try something else, something easier than booting into another operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the printer settings will cause this, make sure you have the right paper size and orientation selected in the printer properties, sometimes the printer does not pick up the page formatting from the application, you can also export as pdf and then try to print the pdf with Adobe Acrobat reader, in the Acrobat reader print dialog, check "Choose paper source by PDF page size".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've set the envelope size in the settings.  I guess I'll just have to continue using Windows when I want to print envelopes.  I guess there aren't many Ubuntu users with Epson printers?  A Google search has revealed that this bug has existed for years.....

Comment: Did you try the PDF method? That probably would be a little bit better than going to windows :)

Comment: No, I haven't, and I shouldn't have to.  It ought to just work right....

Answer (score 0):

It appears Ubuntu 10.10 users trying to print envelopes to an Epson RX580 printer are out of luck.  I cannot find any procedure that allows users to manually define "page size" in Cups. We are stuck with the Cup's defaults.  I am a newbe to Ubuntu 10.10, so hopefully there is a Cups expert out there that can help.  I would be satisfied if Cups would allow me to manually define my desired "page size" rather than being forced to choose from the limited menu options.

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice stubbornly refuses to print to custom paper sizes on any printer.  One thing you can try is to change your printer driver, which will give you more standard paper sizes to choose from.

Open your printer properties from System > Administration > Printing and select "Choose..." next to "Make and Model."  You'll notice there are two drivers for your printer model -- one that says "Simplified," which is the default driver, and one that doesn't.  If you choose the driver that isn't "simplified," then restart OpenOffice, you get a *much* longer list of paper sizes (including "Commercial 10" which is the most common US envelope).

Also remember that OpenOffice does **not** choose the paper size based on the document's page size -- you have to select it manually by clicking on "Properties..." in the print dialog.

Comment: I've installed IBM's Lotus Symphony suite, and I'm pleased to say that it prints envelopes just fine!  I still wish someone would fix OpenOffice, though, as Symphony takes too long to launch, plus I hate having to launch the whole suite!  By the way, I've never downgraded anyone's comments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this is not a great answer, but I'll tell what I do. I have to print custom cards at office and I have had hard experiences with a not-so-supported printer, so i just went back to the basics.

I measured my cards and created the textboxes acordingly in OpenOffice Draw. It assumes I'm using US Letter and I just have to be careful with my boundaries. Envelopes required me to rotate the text. No problems so far. I use a template for each kind of card and it only required me some extra work at the first time.

I understand that my problem has more to do with my hardware and as there is no other option, I'm happy with this work-around. I could even create the file for you if you really need it.